# error en condicional con pasword verify

Tags: php, html, condiciones

cuando le ingreso un usuario y clave registrado funciona hasta la ultima condicional en php

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once 'conexion.php';

$usuario_login= $_POST['nombre_usuario']; <br>
$clave_login=$_POST['clave'];<br>


$sql='SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = ?';<br>
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare($sql);<br>
$sentencia-> execute (array($usuario_login));<br>
$resultado= $sentencia-> fetch();<br>



if (!$resultado){ //matar operacion
header('Location: index.php');    
} else {
echo 'usuario verificado';
}


if (password_verify($clave_login, $resultado ['clave'])){
//contraseñas iguales
echo '<a href="registros/menu.php">Menu</a>';
} else {
echo '**Las contraseñas no concuerdan'**;
die ();
}
```

La condicion verifica al usuario pero no se que esta mal para que diga que las contraseñas no concuerdan. Es decir quiero descubrir mi error en el condicional final que obliga el else que señala que las contraseñas no concuerdan
El resultado que me sale es:

```
usuario verificado
Las contraseñas no concuerdan
```

Se supone que debe ser:

```
usuario verificado
Menu
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En tu código hay varios `<br>` que entiendo que no existen en tu código real, ¿verdad? ¿podrías editar la preguntar y quitarlos? Además, hay un inicio de comentario (`/*`)que no cierras en ningún lado, ¿podrías dejar tu código lo más exacto posible al real?

Comment: Agrega esto `var_dump($resultado);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Le puse el var dump como pediste ¿donde crees que este mi error?     array(6)    {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(4) "user"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["clave"]=>
  string(4) "code"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "code"
}
usuario verificado
string(4) "code"

 Las contraseñas no concuerdan